# defining operator + , = and +=

Tags: c#, c++, operator-overloading

I once read the following statement from a C++ notes,

> In C++, defining operator + and = does not give the right meaning to +=. This language-design bug is fixed in C#

I would like to know what exactly does this statement want to say? Is that related to operator overload?

Comment: The author is not a C++ expert.  Ignore him or her.

Comment: I think the author of that statement want to say that he's ignorant about C++. In particular that he doesn't understand why manually overloading `+=` in C++ makes sense and why it wouldn't make sense in C#. Where did you find that statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer C++ operator overloading mechanism. It definitely not a design bug according to me.

`+`, `=` and `+=` are three different operators. If you want to use `+=` you need to overload `+=`. Overloading `+` and `=` won't make `+=` work.

I would like to add that in `E1 += E2` `E1` gets evaluated only once as far as C++ is concerned. I don't know the exact rules in C#.

Comment: In C#, nothing gets evaluated twice.  But `E1`'s getter and setter will both be evaluated.

Comment: @Ben : And that's why I said that I dont know the rules in C#. Thanks for the info BTW :-)

Answer (score 2):

It says, that in C# if you have overloaded operator + C# automatically will emulate operator += as combination of + and = (`a=a+b` is equal to `a+=b`). In C++ it's not implemented, but it's not a bug. In C++ + and = doesn't give you += because mostly += works  faster than  +, because there is no need to create one more object.

That's why mostly operator + is writen using += operator. Consider fallowing code:

```
class foo
{
public:
   foo& operator+=(const foo& rhs)
   {
   //.......
   }
};
const foo operator+(const foo& lhs,const foo& rhs)
{
   foo temp = lhs;
   return temp+= rhs;
}
```

Comment: First sentence is meaningless, because C# doesn't allow overloading operator `=`.

Comment: And allowing overloading of `+=` in a language where you can't overload `=` makes no sense. Since an object with overloaded `+=` that mutates the left side without an overloaded `=` has horribly broken semantics.

Comment: C# does not allow operator overloading = since it does not allow direct pointer management. Its behavior is fixed based on whether it is reference or value type

Comment: @Ashot: +1, but it's recommended to pass-by-value instead of passing-by-reference and then making a copy inside the function, a pass-by-value argument gives the compiler different optimization opportunities.

Comment: @Ben Voigt you are right, and in my first version of answer I have passed by value, but than I thought, that such code looks little confusing for beginner.

Answer (score 0):

It means that in C++ if you defined your own operator `+` and operator `=` for your class, that still does not mean that your class will automatically support the `+=` operator. If you want the `+=` operator to work for your class, you have to define the `+=` explicitly and separately.

In C#, if I understood it correctly, defining operators `+` and `=` for your class will also mean that you'll be able to use operator `+=` with your class. The `+=` will be "emulated" through combination of operator `+` and operator `=`. E.g. expression `a += b` will be interpreted as `a = a + b`.

It doesn't work that way in C++. If you don't define the `+=` explicitly, `a += b` will result in compiler error, even if you have `+` and `=` defined.

Comment: I'd like to add that it is not an bug, that the creation of `+` and `=` does not automatically create an `+=`-operator. The `+` creates an new object from two objects and returns the new one. The `+=` has no need to create an new object, it could modify the target-object directly.

Comment: C# doesn't even allow overloading operator `=`.

Answer (score 0):

C# does not allow operator overloading = since it does not allow direct pointer management. Its behavior is fixed based on whether it is reference or value type. For the same reason you cannot overload += . It's meaning will always be doing the sum and assignment. You can only therefore decide what the meaning for + is to your datastructure.